# Wrapping a method from outside the class in Python with decorator

Tags: python, configparser

I would like to ask a question, how I can override/extend the existing external python class. I wanted to be able to call the same API, like parent class, but with some modifications.

Something like that:

```ini
[a]
b = 1
```

```py
import configparser

# my wrapper class
class MyConfigParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
    # override/wrap the parent class with all arguments (could be some optionals too) parent function has the same name, but it shouldn't be called
    def getint(self, section, option):
        # call the parent function, pass all args (maybe without mentioning them, ideally without copying them)
        ret = parent.get(section, option)
        # make modifications
        print("my wrapper")
        ret = ret + 1
        # return modified value
        return ret

config = MyConfigParser()
# call parent function
config.read('my-file.ini')
# call my wrapped-function
a = config.getint('a','b')
```

Just for an information, I'm unable to modify the parent class.
How to do that?

Comment: I am not sure, but it doesn't sound like "decorator" or "wrapping" are the right words here. It seems that all you want to do is subclass `ConfigParser`, override its `getint` method and have your method call the superclass' `getint` method. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't mean, that I have create a new subclass. I just wanted to be able to change the base class behaviour.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well you can always monkey-patch the base class, but that is usually a terrible idea. Other than that, I see no other way than subclassing.

Comment: No no, as I have written already. That's something what I don't want to do.

Comment: Extending classes via subclasses is basically the entire premise of object oriented programming. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about what a [**decorator**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator) is and what the word *wrapping* typically refers to. Neither of those apply here, if I understood your intent correctly.

Of course you can subclass some existing class that you may or may not have any control over and override its methods. And of course you can conveniently call the parent class' methods from inside your own methods. In Python you typically use the built in [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) proxy class for that. But none of this has anything to do with decoration or wrapping.

If you want to override a superclass' method, you should take care to match its signature. Otherwise you would be violating type safety. If all you care about are a few specific arguments but not all of them, you can cheat a bit and collect the rest in the catch-all `*args, **kwargs` parameters, but you should then pass them along to the superclass' method call.

Also, you seemed to be calling the [`ConfigParser.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.get) method inside your overridden [`getint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.getint) method. But I am pretty sure that was a typo/mistake because you are clearly expecting the returned value that you assign to `ret` to be an `int`, whereas [`get`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/configparser.pyi#L145) returns a `str`. So you should be calling `super().getint(...)` there.

Finally, if we are already at it, it is good form to properly annotate your functions with types. (see [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) for details)

Here is what I think you need:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
from typing import Any


class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser):
    def getint(self, section: str, option: str, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> int:
        ret = super().getint(section, option, *args, **kwargs)
        print("overridden `getint`")
        ret += 1
        return ret  # type: ignore[no-any-return]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = MyConfigParser()
    config.read("my-file.ini")
    print(config.getint("a", "b"))
```

The output with your example `ini`-file:

```
overridden `getint`
2
```

There are a lot of questions and answers on this platform about `super` and `subclassing` as well as `decorators`. I would suggest you search a bit and read up on those.

Comment: Thank you for this proposal ;). Last question is about the parent function calling. Correct me if I am wrong, but if I call `getint`, it will call the function from `MyConfigParser` not from parent even if they have the same name, right? So it means, that function is completely override n.

Comment: Yes, in my example code, when I call `config.getint`, the Python interpreter sees that `config` is of the class `MyConfigParser` and thus first checks if that class defines `getint`. Since it does, that is what is executed (_not_ that of the parent class). If it didn't have that method, the interpreter would continue looking if its parent class has that method and so on. This is called method resolution order ([MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order)).